# Postfix: change sender and relay host

Tags: postfix

I manage a Postfix 2.11 mail server on a Debian 8.9.
I need, for some specific address, to rewrite the sender and to relay the message through a specific host; I'm able to do both things separately (I use the transport_maps to specify the relay host and a custom transport to rewrite the sender address) but I didn't find a way to do them together.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I use the transport_maps to deviate specific messages to a simple python script listening locally. In the script I modify what I need then I send to my specific relay host.

Thanks to all